# Entering the UK whilst pregnant?

Tags: uk, health, customs-and-immigration, pregnancy

Is it possible to be refused entry at UK passport control, if I am visiting the UK for 3 weeks to celebrate our wedding (to my UK husband)?

I worry that they will think I am attempting to move there to stay and make use of the NHS for giving birth but this is not the case. We live and work in Russia, so what if I take proof of work, return tickets, doctor's bills, etc., would it be sufficient evidence of my intent to return home?

Comment: The UK is less funny about this sort of thing than the US, as it doesn't operate *Jus Soli* citizenship.

Comment: Unless you are literally on the cusp of giving birth (in which case I imagine you would have been prevented from flying) then I imagine you will be fine

Comment: Be aware that you are going to need medical insurance which will cover you in case you give birth prematurely, and also that you can't actually get married in Britain without a special visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth states celebrate to husband so presume they're already married and celebrating it with UK family. 

Kid will be British anyway due to the Father. Make sure you have travel insurance so you don't get charged if you do give birth in the UK, only UK residents are covered by the NHS for "free".

Comment: I presume that too. But I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @CMaster the UK does have somewhat weakened jus soli since children  born there to settled foreigners are citizens from birth. But it also has jus sanguinis (also somewhat limited), so unless the father is a British citizen by descent the child will be a citizen of the UK no matter where the birth takes place. But the question raises the issue of NHS care, not citizenship.

Comment: @BritishSam, "*to celebrate our wedding*" is a perfectly idiomatic way of saying "*to get married*", and the three week stay was until recently the shortest possible to get married (one week before you can publish the banns and then two after). As of 2015 it's five weeks (one and four).

Comment: @PeterTaylor celebrating wedding, already married. e.g. having a party at home.

Comment: Being born in the UK makes a legal difference if either father or mother is British not by descent (it makes the baby British not by descent vs British by descent), if either father or mother is British by descent (it makes the baby British vs. not British), or the parents are settled foreigners in the UK (British vs. not British). So with British husband you want the child to be born in the UK. If the British husband is British by descent (for example born in Russia with British parents), you _really_ want the baby born in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your passport and any visa/documentation is in order I see no reason to worry. I think you will find the passport control people to be courteous and professional. Your husband is British (by the sound of it?) so there should be no problem. You would be very unlikely to be stopped due to your pregnancy, pregnant women are treated with respect in the UK. If you have a return ticket there will be no reason to treat you suspiciously.

Answer (score 0):

I've travelled while 6 and 8 months pregnant and I was never stopped for this reason. You should have nothing to worry about, but it's great that you prepared additional documents to prove your intentions to give birth in your home country, and not the UK.

Comment: Your website indicates that you are an EU citizen, so your experience of being admitted to the UK while pregnant is not relevant to a Russian woman because you entered the UK under EU freedom of movement.